# I've got trouble linking Pistache using Qt Creator : undefined reference to `vtable for Pistache::Http::Handler'

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm using Qc Creator and I'm trying to link & compile Pistache.
In my doc.pro I've add

```
LIBS += -L -lpistache
```

I wanted to test the 'HelloWorld' sample code, but no success :

undefined reference to `vtable for Pistache::Http::Handler'.
Here is the sample code :

```
#define API_H

#include <pistache/net.h>
#include <pistache/http.h>
#include <pistache/peer.h>
#include <pistache/http_headers.h>
#include <pistache/cookie.h>
#include <pistache/endpoint.h>
#include <pistache/common.h>

using namespace Pistache;
using namespace std;


class api : public Http::Handler
{
private:



public:
    HTTP_PROTOTYPE(api)

    void onRequest(const Http::Request& request, Http::ResponseWriter response) override{
            UNUSED(request);
            response.send(Pistache::Http::Code::Ok, "Hello World\n");
        }

    api();

};

#endif // API_H
```

Comment: I don't think the -L is correct however I may be wrong. `-L` is supposed to have a directory parameter.

Comment: So I find out how to solve it.
In my "app.pro" file, I've just add :
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += libpistache

And problem solved ! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I find out how to solve it. In my "app.pro" file, I've just add :

```
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig 
PKGCONFIG += libpistache
```

And problem solved ! :)